# Python.NET - Sending data to a DataGridView

Tags: python, .net, datagridview, clr, ironpython

To give some background, I am attempting to use Python to give some of my users an interface through a third-party program (that already has IronPython embedded) to add, edit, and delete records from a SQL Server database.

I've received good assistance from one member [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66781011/python-net-winforms-how-to-pass-info-from-a-textbox-to-a-button-click-event) about Python .NET Winforms so I am attempting to get some more assistance. My goal is to populate a DataGridView (dgv) with records from a table. Seems pretty simple. However, when I run the code, my dgv is just an empty container.

I could use some assistance or better yet, point me in the right direction to find the answer. I am willing to learn.

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
clr.AddReference("System.Data")
clr.AddReference("System.Globalization")

from System.Windows.Forms import *
from System.Drawing import *
from System.Data import *
from System.Data.SqlClient import *
from System.Globalization import *

class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):

        # Setup the form
        self.Text = "Calculated Control Limits Form"
        self.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.startposition?view=net-5.0

        # Create &  configure the DataGridView label
        self.setupDataGridViewLabel()

        # Create, configure, and populate data for the DataGridView
        self.setupDataGridView()
        self.PopulateDataGridView("SELECT * FROM SPC_CALCULATED_CONTROL_LIMITS")

        # Create & configure a line seperator
        self.setupSeperator()
        
        # Create & configure a Label to grab the users Employee ID
        self.setupEmployeeIDLabel()
        
        # Create & configure a label for the Lower Control Limit Label
        self.Load_LCL_Label()
        
        # Create & configure a TextBox for the Lower Control Limit
        self.Load_LCL_TextBox()
        
        # Create & configure a label for the Target Mean
        self.LoadTargetMeanLabel()
        
        # Create & configure a TextBox for the Target Mean
        self.LoadTargetMeanTextBox()
        
        # Create & configure a label for the Upper Control Limit
        self.Load_UCL_Label()
        
        # Create & configure a TextBox for the Upper Control Limit
        self.Load_UCL_TextBox()
        
        # Create & configure a label for the Comment
        self.LoadCommentLabel()
        
        # Create a TextBox for the Comment
        self.LoadCommentTextBox()
        
        # Create & configure the button
        self.LoadButton()

#       Register the event handler
        self.button.Click += self.button_Click
        
        self.Size = Size (550, self.button.Bottom + self.button.Height + 15)
        
        #Load the Controls to the Form
        self.Controls.Add(self.lblCCL)
        self.Controls.Add(self.dgvCCL)
        
        self.Controls.Add(self.button)
        
        self.Controls.Add(self.lblSep)
        
        self.Controls.Add(self.lblEmpID)
        
        self.Controls.Add(self.lblLCL)
        self.Controls.Add(self.txtLCL)
        
        self.Controls.Add(self.lblTarget)
        self.Controls.Add(self.txtTarget)
        
        self.Controls.Add(self.lblUCL)
        self.Controls.Add(self.txtUCL)
        
        self.Controls.Add(self.lblComment)
        self.Controls.Add(self.txtComment)

    def button_Click(self, sender, args):
        self.Close()
        
    def setupDataGridView(self):            
        self.dgvCCL = DataGridView()
        self.dgvCCL.AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
        self.dgvCCL.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
        self.dgvCCL.Location = Point(self.lblCCL.Left, self.lblCCL.Bottom + 5)
        self.dgvCCL.Size = Size(500, 250)
        self.dgvCCL.TabIndex = 3
        #self.dgvCCL.ColumnCount = len(headers)
        self.dgvCCL.ColumnHeadersVisible = True
        
    def setupSeperator(self):
        self.lblSep = Label()
        self.lblSep.Size = Size(500, 2)
        self.lblSep.BackColor = Color.DarkGray
        self.lblSep.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        self.lblSep.Location = Point(self.dgvCCL.Left, self.dgvCCL.Bottom + 10)
        
    def setupDataGridViewLabel(self):
        self.lblCCL = Label()
        self.lblCCL.Text = "Calculated Control Limits View"
        self.lblCCL.Font = Font(self.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        self.lblCCL.Location = Point(10, 10)
        self.lblCCL.BorderStyle  = 0 # BorderStyle.None --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.borderstyle?view=net-5.0
        self.lblCCL.Size = Size(self.lblCCL.PreferredWidth, self.lblCCL.PreferredHeight)

    def setupEmployeeIDLabel(self):
        self.lblEmpID = Label()
        self.lblEmpID.Text = 'login.computeruser.upper()'
        self.lblEmpID.Font = Font(self.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        self.lblEmpID.Size = Size(self.lblEmpID.PreferredWidth, self.lblEmpID.PreferredHeight)
        self.lblEmpID.Location = Point(self.dgvCCL.Right - self.lblEmpID.Width, self.dgvCCL.Top - 15)
        self.lblEmpID.BorderStyle = 0

    def Load_LCL_Label(self):
        self.lblLCL = Label()
        self.lblLCL.Text = 'Lower Control Limit'
        self.lblLCL.Size = Size(self.lblLCL.PreferredWidth, self.lblLCL.PreferredHeight)
        self.lblLCL.Location = Point(self.lblSep.Left + 65, self.lblSep.Top + 15)
        self.lblLCL.BorderStyle = 0

    def Load_LCL_TextBox(self):
        self.txtLCL = TextBox()
        self.txtLCL.Size = Size(100, 50)
        self.txtLCL.Location = Point(self.lblLCL.Left, self.lblLCL.Bottom + 3)

    def LoadTargetMeanLabel(self):
        self.lblTarget = Label()
        self.lblTarget.Text = 'Target Mean'
        self.lblTarget.Size = Size(self.lblLCL.PreferredWidth, self.lblLCL.PreferredHeight)
        self.lblTarget.Location = Point(self.lblLCL.Left + 125, self.lblSep.Top + 15)
        self.lblTarget.BorderStyle = 0

    def LoadTargetMeanTextBox(self):
        self.txtTarget = TextBox()
        self.txtTarget.Size = Size(100, 50)
        self.txtTarget.Location = Point(self.lblLCL.Left + 125, self.lblLCL.Bottom + 3)

    def Load_UCL_Label(self):
        self.lblUCL = Label()
        self.lblUCL.Text = 'Upper Control Limit'
        self.lblUCL.Size = Size(self.lblUCL.PreferredWidth, self.lblUCL.PreferredHeight)
        self.lblUCL.Location = Point(self.lblTarget.Left + 125, self.lblSep.Top + 15)
        self.lblUCL.BorderStyle = 0

    def Load_UCL_TextBox(self):
        self.txtUCL = TextBox()
        self.txtUCL.Size = Size(100, 50)
        self.txtUCL.Location = Point(self.lblTarget.Left + 125, self.lblLCL.Bottom + 3)

    def LoadCommentLabel(self):
        self.lblComment = Label()
        self.lblComment.Text = 'Comment'
        self.lblComment.Size = Size(self.lblUCL.PreferredWidth, self.lblUCL.PreferredHeight)
        self.lblComment.Location = Point(self.lblSep.Left, 350)
        self.lblComment.BorderStyle = 0

    def LoadCommentTextBox(self):
        self.txtComment = TextBox()
        self.txtComment.Multiline = True
        self.txtComment.Size = Size(500, 50)
        self.txtComment.Location = Point(self.lblSep.Left, self.lblComment.Bottom + 5)

    def LoadButton(self):
        self.button = Button()
        self.button.Size = Size(100, 30)
        self.button.Location = Point(self.lblSep.Left, self.txtComment.Bottom + 10)
        self.button.Text = "Click Me!"

    def PopulateDataGridView(self, selectcommand):
        bs = BindingSource()

        try:
            connectionstring = "YourSQLServerConnectionString"

            # Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
            da = SqlDataAdapter(selectcommand, connectionstring)

            # Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and delete commands based on selectCommand.
            cb = SqlCommandBuilder(da)

            # Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            dt = DataTable()
            Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            da.Fill(dt)
            bs.DataSource = dt

            # Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
            self.dgvCCL.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)

            #String connectionString =
                #"Data Source=<SQL Server>;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" +
                #"Integrated Security=True";

            #// Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
            #dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            #// Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            #// delete commands based on selectCommand.
            #SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            #// Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            #DataTable table = new DataTable
            #{
             #   Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            #};
            #dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            #bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

            #// Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
            #dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
                #DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);

        except SqlException:
            Messagebox.Show("Something happened.")

Application.EnableVisualStyles()
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

Application.Run(MyForm())
```

Comment: I do not see anywhere in the code where the grids `DataSource` has been set. I would guess inside the `PopulateDataGridView` method you need a line like… `self.dgvCCL.DataSource = bs`. Is the grid’s `DataSource` getting set somewhere else?

Comment: @JohnG that was it. I wasn't setting my datasource. Thanks a bunch.